# Java 9 Splashscreen Problem with Splashscreen.getSplashScreen();

Tags: java, splash-screen

I have a little problem with getting my java splashscreen working! I´m using Eclipse and Java 9. Referring to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html I tried to use the method `SplashScreen.getScreenSplash();`. But this does not work. Instead the error message says that this method doesn´t exists. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplashScreen extends JFrame {
    private SplashScreen sp;
    private JLabel label;

    public SplashScreen() {
        super("SplashScreen");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        label = new JLabel("Welcome");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        sp = SplashScreen.getScreenSplash();

        if(sp != null) {
            Graphics2D g = sp.createGraphics();
            g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
            g.setPaintMode();
            //printing the progress bar
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(100, 200, 200, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(100, 200, 2*i, 20);
                sp.update(g);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Does anyone know what has changed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SplashScreen.getScreenSplash() !=  SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
```

You've mixed the words up.

Comment: Ok thanks! But I also tried ` SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();` and this doesn´t work anyway. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/SplashDemoProject/src/misc/SplashDemo.java

Comment: The linked example compiles fine for me. You still get the same error message?

Comment: Which jdk are you using?

Comment: Very confusing I tried the linked code on my linux machine and it worked fine. Whereas at my windows 10 I still get the erorr. Thanks anyway!